# nginx proxy_pass - How to handle HTTP 303 "See Other"

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx setup where I need to proxy a specific external server because the server is protected by firewall rules. Only my reverse proxy (nginx) is allowed to access this server. My configuration looks like this:

```
events {}
http {
  server {          
      listen 80;
      server_name ceph-dashboard;    
      location / {
        proxy_pass https://node1.foo.com:8443;
        proxy_ssl_verify            off;
      }
  }
}
```

This works fine until in some situations node1.foo.com is not responding with `200` but with a `303 (See Other)` providing a different server location (e.g. https://node2.foo.com:8443). This other server is a member of the cluster which is also protected by firewall rules.

In my current setup the nginx is simply providing this result `302` to the client browser. But the clients browser is not be allowed to access node2.foo.com because of the firewall rule. But my nginx reverse proxy server is allowed to access this second host.

How can I configure nginx in a way that the `proxy_pass` configuration is handling the HTTP response `303` internally and switching to the node2.foo.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
    server {          
      listen 80;
      server_name ceph-i-dashboard;    
      location / {
        proxy_pass https://node1.foo.com:8443;
        proxy_ssl_verify            off;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 301 302 303 307 = @handle_redirect;
      }

     location @handle_redirect {
       set $saved_redirect_location '$upstream_http_location';
       proxy_pass $saved_redirect_location;
     }
```